# Bootstrap 4 search filter

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I want to make search filter, but I found only the filter which is showing only searching item, not box. Any Idea how can I make it? It's my code:
**HTML:**

```
foreach($results as $row) { 
    echo '<div class="col-md-3">';
      echo '<div class="card" >';
        echo '<div class="card-body">';
          echo '<h5 class="card-title">'.$row->cm_name.' '.$row->cm_surname.'</h5>';
          echo '<h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Dodano: '.mdate($dateString, $row->cm_added_date).'</h6>';
          echo '<p class="card-text">Nr. Tel: +48 '.chunk_split($row->cm_phone, 3, ' ').'</p>';
          echo '<a href="#" class="card-link">Edytuj</a>';
          echo '<a href="'.base_url('core/customers/delete/'.$row->cm_id).'" class="card-link">Usuń</a>';
        echo '</div>';
      echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>'; }
```

**And here is script:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#searchInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#searchBox *").filter(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
   });
  });
});
```

**And attached screens:**
[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M73g7.png)
[Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0t5f.png)

Comment: provide sufficient inputs to explain problem

Comment: What's on your mind?

Comment: what is this #searchBox

Comment: There are all persons. https://i.imgur.com/t8Y9z8i.png

Comment: In this part try `$(document).on("keyup", "#searchInput",  function() {` I don't see the `#searchInput` id any where

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `.filter` needs to return a value of either true or false. You then need to do something to the array of nodes that it gives you.

```
$("#searchBox *").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().toremoveLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
}).hideOrDoWhateverYouLike();
```

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: Add a console.log($("#searchbox *")); to your code and see what comes up in the console

Comment: Ok - this should work. Filter is just filtering the nodes. You need to do something to them afterwards. See the edited code:

Comment: I don't have any idea.

Comment: Could you clarify, using more words?